# How can I get the indices of QListWidget::selectedItems()?

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget, qlistwidgetitem

I have `QListWidget` and I need to get the indices of selected items. (I could work with items in the list by values, but I have `std::vector` that contains some objects for each item in the list and I also need to delete them from it.)
There is a fucntion `indexFromItem` but it's protected(?) so I can't use it.

Any ideas?

```
QList<QListWidgetItem *> itemList = lw1->selectedItems();
```

Comment: Unsure about your case but the index is applicable to certain model and QListWidget is designed for handling individual items rather than model. You have QListWidgetItem * itemAt(int x, int y) const with x and y for 'indexes'.

Comment: Are you looking for the `QModelIndex` or the integral index of the item in the list (i.e. its position)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use maybe:

```
list->selectionModel()->selectedIndexes()
```

Where `list` is an instance of `QListWidget`.
Not sure if it returns exactly what you are looking for.

From the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qitemselectionmodel.html#selectedIndexes):

> Returns a list of all selected model item indexes. The list contains no duplicates, and is not sorted.

`QListWidget` has a method named `selectedIndexes` as well, but it is a protected one, so you have to use such a tricky way to get them.

Answer (score 2):

i'm not sure that is right way, but it works for me:

```cpp
void ScannerWindow::on_ipList_itemDoubleClicked(QListWidgetItem *item)
{
    qDebug() << ui->ipList->row(item);
}
```

where `ui->ipList` is a `QListWidget`

Comment: 0) You are not using slots, generated by Creator, are you? 1) The question was about _selected_ indices, `QListWidget` provides different kinds of selection, but in general you can select more than one item and do it not only via double-clicking them. 2) So, your solution works for only one row, selected only with a double click.

Comment: 0) this slot was generated automatically, by Creator
2) yes, "double-click" is just my case, but it works also for `itemClicked(QListWidgetItem *item)`
...
i try to select more than one row in `QListWidget` and i can't.

Comment: if you change `selectionMode` to anything other than SingleSelection/NoSelection, you'll be able to use Ctrl/Shift, arrow keys and get multiple items selected. And what is worse, possibly without clicking each of them.